# How to concat() two elements in XSLT, when one of them might not exist?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to build a fixed-width text file from an XML source. Other solutions aside, my approach is as follows:

`<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(wd:MailAdd/wd:CD-CITY-MAIL-ADD, $eightySpaces), 1, 26)"/>`

Essentially, concatenate the value for the given field, with a whole bunch of spaces. Then substring the first # of characters of that result, so you only have the width of that field.

For a record with a city `BRYAN` and another record with a city `ONE LONG INCREDIBLY UNBROKEN SENTENCE` The result above produces something like:
`BRYAN_____________________`
and
`ONE LONG INCREDIBLY UNBROK`

The problem is when one of the elements is not present in the source XML (any record may or may not have an address). The XSLT is just skipping that concat statement, and moving to the next line. Which I suppose could make sense if concat() doesn't know how to concatenate an XPath that it can't find.

Is there a way to force `concat()` to concatenate the variable with nothing, if the first argument evaluates to nothing?

Comment: This doesn't sound quite right, as `concat` should indeed work with a non-existent node. (See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcX for a contrived example). You might need to show more of your XSLT as one reason for it appearing not to work is maybe that your `xsl:value-of` statement is not evening being reached. (i.e. Maybe it is contained in an `<xsl:if test="wd:MailAdd/wd:CD-CITY-MAIL-ADD">` statement)

Comment: This is good information, thanks. I probably need to look more closely at what it's actually doing. The symptom might not be what I think. There's no logic around any of these. Just for each Root/Child write out all these node values to a text file.

Comment: * sigh * user error. For some elements I'm not doing any concatenation because the data will always be the same length (such as dates that I'm pre-formatting to be yyyymmdd)... unless they're not there at all. Since I'm not doing the concatenation for those, there are no spaces getting put in place of the missing data.